# Matlab GUI Edit Text Box: how to add a line instead of replacing all content?

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-guide

Is there any way to do that? I want to give information about what is going on in simulation during it. I can obviously set the text as `previousString + newString` every time but it's taking so much time.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear how the simulation log is generated and, perhaps, saved (in a log file? Is it directly available within the GUI?).

Nevertheless, a possible solution could be:

- set the size of the textbox to diplay "some" rows (e. g. max 4)
- use cellarrays to set / store each row  of the simulation log to be displayed in the textbox. Cellarrays allows managing multiple text rows of different length (cellarray to be added to GUI `handles` through `guidata`)
- each time a new string has to be diplayed, add it to the cellarray
- check for the maximum number of rows to be diplayed in the textbox:

  - if the maximum number hsa been reached, shift up the content of the cellarray and add the new string to the last position in the cellarray

I've built a simple GUI with a textbox with max 4 rows and a pushbutton to add the string (to simulate the "simulation log).

The string counter has been initialized in the GUI `OpeningFcn` as follows:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Get GUIDATA
gui_my_data=guidata(handles.figure1);
% Add string counter to handles
gui_my_data.str_cnt=0;
% Update GUIDATA
guidata(handles.figure1,gui_my_data);
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

In the pushbutton `Callback` I've inserted the code for the updating of the textbox content as follows:

```
function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% Get GUIDATA
gui_my_data=guidata(handles.figure1);
% Get string counter from GUIDATA
n_rows=gui_my_data.str_cnt;
% If maximum rows to be diplayed not reached, add the new string
if(n_rows < 4)
   n_rows=n_rows+1;
   if(n_rows == 1)
      c_str=cellstr(get(handles.text1,'string'));
   else
      c_str=get(handles.text1,'string');
   end
% Generate the new string   
   c_str{n_rows}=['row #' num2str(n_rows)];
% Update textbox content
   set(handles.text1,'string',c_str);
% Save string counter
   gui_my_data.str_cnt=n_rows;
else
% If maximum rows to be diplayed reached, get the strings
   c_str=get(handles.text1,'string');
% Shift up previous string
   c_str(1:3)=c_str(2:4);
   n_rows=n_rows+1;
   gui_my_data.str_cnt=n_rows;
% Generate the new string and add it to the textbox
   c_str{4}=['riga #' num2str(n_rows)];
   set(handles.text1,'string',c_str);
end
% Update GUIDATA
guidata(handles.figure1,gui_my_data);
```

[image]

Hope this helps.